# Foreign text in Blender isn't processed correctly

Tags: text-object

Blender has issues when dealing with non-English characters.

- I can't enter Russian text in 3D objects.
- Blender displays folder and file names incorrectly if they are in Russian.

Is there a solution to these text-encoding problems?

**UPDATE**

[Demonstration of impossibility of entering letters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=co96RhU5nLc)

Demonstration of only `Bfont` available:

[image]

Comment: What does it mean "I can't enter Russian text" and "displays folder and file names incorrectly"? How are these displayed?

Comment: @Bakuriu instead of Russian filenames some garbage of extraterrestrial symbols is displayed. In text object Russian letters are impossible to enter -- they are "eated" by Blender.

Comment: @SuzanCioc You need to [load fonts into blender](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Texts#Loading_and_Changing_Fonts). You can do this by clicking one of the folder icons under *Font* in your screenshot.

Comment: This is bug report worthy. Blender completely ignores IMEs and other input methods. Both in the text editor and for the edit mode of text. Going so far as to lead to faulty input (when typing たまご it captures たごご or similar things in certain edge cases)

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5118/599

Answer (score 9):

**Interface**
The wiki page on [Blender Internationalization](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Internationalization) shows how to set your preferred language

**3D**
[image]

You can enter foreign languages with alternative symbols (like a cyrillic alphabet). You must pick a font that supports the extended character set. The default Bfont does not have many extended characters, that's why you aren't seeing them. You can read more about support for fonts on the [Modeling/Text](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Texts) wiki page

**3D using the Text Editor**

[image]

Comment: I don't want to translate UI, I just want to type some text into text object. I have only `Bfont` in available fonts.

Comment: Looks like `Internation font` option helped to display filenames correctly, but still don't know hot to type international. I want to set international font by default, not `Bfont`

Comment: @SuzanCioc - hjaarnio's method is worth doing, you can copy the text from an external application into blender's  TextEditor then go Edit > Text to 3D Object.

Comment: This is very complex. I want to enter text from keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

To input text that can't be directly typed from the keyboard, it is possible to copy-paste it into Blender's text editor and use *Edit* > *Text to 3d object* from the header, which will make a text object out of it. Shortcuts are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to make it one object and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to make a object from each line.

Comment: This is very complex. I want to enter text from keyboard

Answer (score 3):

As zeffi pointed out, setting the preferences to use a Russian font is the answer to getting your filenames looking correct.

Blender doesn't use these international settings when working with a 3DText object. Blenders default font for a text object is a simple plain font that is rarely used in a final project and as you have found isn't good with non-english characters. It is common practice to select a different font for any text objects in blender, and the font used is very much a personal preference.

One way to make it easier is to add a bookmark for your fonts folder, that way when you add a text object you can easily get to the folder containing your fonts. You can also set a default fonts folder in preferences as the location blender will start looking for fonts.

Another option is to customise your [startup.blend file](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Vitals/Default_scene). You can setup a scene any way you want and save it as your startup file. Anytime you start blender or select File->New the contents of your startup.blend is used. By having a text object setup with the font you want to use in the startup.blend it will always be ready for you to use.

Comment: Why bookmark when you can set blender to search for them in *User Preferences > File*? (though bookmarking is good too) :)