# How can I add text in a non-english language?

Tags: text-object, text-editor

How can I add text with non Latin characters?

I'd like to get text in other languages like Arabic, Russin (Cyrilic), Japanese, Chinese, Malayalam among others, but I get rectangles instead of Arabic letters.

Comment: I found this directly on google. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCoC89m3yGQ

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2687/599

Comment: A guess, but: - Ensure you have loaded a font supporting required glyphs. - Try using paste text from file function from the menu.

Comment: No, Blender doesn't support Arabic or Udru. I have fonts installed with OS support. but still, blender doesn't support it. Using a virtual keyboard to flip the letters wont help too, as they won't be joined as required. Only reasonable option left is to write them up in inkscape and import the svg in blender. (Convert your text to path , before saving svg file).
http://i59.tinypic.com/2nis1gx.png

Answer (score 18):

First of all, Blender does **not** support Right-to-Left text rendering, however there are ways to use a wide variety of character sets.

## In a 3D text object:

The default *Bfont* has a very limited character set which does not include arabic.
To add arabic text to a 3D text object, you need to use a font that has the relevant glyphs (e.g. a [unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) font).
Once you find a font that contains arabic characters, you need to load it into blender.

Note that you cannot use [bitmap fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#Bitmap_fonts), as blender needs vector data for generating curves.

##Loading a font:
You can [load a font into blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/texts/properties.html#font) from the *Object data > Font panel*:

1. Add a text object <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Text*
2. With the text object selected, click the file icon for the appropriate styling (e.g. regular, bold, etc.) in *Properties > Object Data > Font*:

[image]

3. Navigate to a font file (`.ttf` `.otf` etc.)  on your system and click *Open Font*:

[image]

The font should now be used for the active text object.

##Entering characters:

If you don't have a keyboard that has Arabic characters, here are some alternate ways to input text:

**method one:**

1. Select the text object and enter edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>. You should see a bar appear that indicates the location of the cursor:

[image]

2. Delete the existing characters (<kbd>Backspace</kbd>) and enter a character. You should see a text field appear in the *Redo menu* at the bottom of the *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd> in the *3D view*):

[image]

3. Select the text box and paste the your text into it, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

Note that you can enable *International fonts* in *User preferences > System* to display arabic charecters in the UI, making the arabic characters visible in the text field:
[image]
More about this later.

**Method two:**

As [mentioned by kivig](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3544/599), there is a *Paste from file* feature.

1. Select the text object and enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. Click *Paste file* in *3D view > Header > Text*:

[image]

3. Navigate to a text file containing the text you wish to put in the text object and press *Paste File*.

## In the Interface:

You can enable [*International Fonts*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/System#International_Fonts) in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> User preferences > System* to display arabic characters:

[image]

This also enables options to translate the UI into many languages, including arabic. See the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Internationalization) for more details:

> From version 2.60, Blender supports international fonts and a range of
> language options for the Interface and Tooltips. To enable it, open
> the *User Preferences* window, *System* tab, and toggle the *International
> Fonts* option in the bottom right-hand corner.
>
> This displays three new settings:
>
> - *Language*
>   drop-down menu where you can select your preferred language.
> - *Interface*
>   to translate the User Interface itself (e.g. controls and menus).
> - *Tooltips*
>   to translate tooltips.

Comment: Method two seems being dropped in 2.70?

Comment: @LeonCheung It was [apparently moved to the "edit menu"](https://developer.blender.org/rB38bbd9c778d6733f21732df1f51dd2dc5236fa44), but I'm not sure what that is..

Comment: In case you're using Blender 2.80, the "International Fonts" checkbox has been replaced by the checkbox in the "Translation" _header_ in Edit > Preferences > Interface. Took me some time to find it.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to type/load texts in Text Editor, then **Edit>Text To 3D Object**.

[image]

However, As you see from the image, the order for arbic characters is
 actually flipped. RTL editing/inputting hasn't been supported yet. You
 have to type / convert all characters flipped per line before that. (There is a [very old solution](http://www.blendernation.com/2008/05/05/using-arabic-scripts-with-blender/) for this, in case it may help some.)

Answer (score 2):

Well for better results of text other than English I would advice you make a SVG file with inkscape and then import it in Blender.

To expand further:

1. Use Inkscape to write your text using the Text Tool: Press <kbd>F8</kbd>  and type away.
2. Convert the text into a path: Select your text object, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. Remove any extraneous groups: Select the newly converted text path and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> multiple times until you see selection boxes around each separate glyph/diacritic.
4. Unify these disparate segments into a single path by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>.

There is currently no way to render properly-shaped Arabic text in Blender alone.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [Inkscape](https://www.inkscape.org/en/) to create a font and save it as a .svg file.  Then in Blender, enable the .svg import addon and import the .svg file that you saved.