# Greek letters in Blender OSX

Tags: text-object

How can I use greek letters for text in Blender 2.71 OSX? I need to use a lower case delta for a partial charge symbol in a chemistry reaction animation.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3522/599

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I searched for "Blender greek letters" and got no results so I posted this question. Should I leave the question for those who might search for greek letters in the future or should I delete it?

Comment: You can just leave it since it will help searches as you said.