# Text appears as string of boxes

Tags: text-object, text-editor

When I use the text tool, my letters always appear as boxes on the side menus and do not appear in the render area. In fact, whenever I type in blender I just get a string of boxes.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you typing non-English characters?

Comment: A little more information would be helpful. For instance what fonts are you using, have you enabled international fonts?

Comment: [duplicate of this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3522/935)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you may be using an international font, while not having enabled them beforehand. Go to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3522/935) for more details.