# How can I make 3D Text in Russian?

Tags: objects, interface, workflow, text-object

I've seen a similar question on BSE about entering foreign languages into 3D Text, but it doesn't help. I've tried using two different fonts (both of which support Russian). I've tried enabling International Fonts in Blender's User Preferences, but it doesn't work as well. It either types English text with Greek letters or displays empty vertical rectangles.

If anyone has been able to add text in any foreign language, please let me know.

I actually found out that it can be easily done through Text Editor, which would be probably the best way for me since I would prefer to paste my text. Can anyone perhaps guide me through?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3522/599

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select your text object and under it's data change the font to use:

[image]

Use a *[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)* font file or a file that has all the symbols you need. On windows machine you can find fonts in:

```
/Windows/Fonts/        (Fonts folder may be hidden)
```

and on linux machine in:

```
/usr/share/fonts
/usr/local/share/fonts
/home/<username>/.fonts       (.fonts is a hidden folder)
```

There are also many font sources in internet. For example [Dafont](http://www.dafont.com/) is a free one.

You can copy-paste the content into the text object, you don't have to use text editor for this.

There should be no problem with russian symbols:

[image]

Or any other symbols:

[image]

Comment: How would I set the font, if i'm copy pasting?

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov you can copy paste the content into the text object (in edit mode). You set the font by selecting the font file you have on hdd or downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a different font file?

You probably have to find a font family that has glyphs for your character set, in this case Russian characters, I am not sure the font shipped by default with Blender default (BFont) has the characters you need.

Try downloading a new one from, say [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/) for example. There's a filter on the left menu to select fonts by script type.