# Does Blender support other languages, such as ML-IN(malayalam) for the text curve?

Tags: text-object

I was trying to trying to create a text curve in my language( ML-IN(malayalam)) and it didn't even show up[image]
please anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: change your font to something that supports the language, https://fonts.google.com/?subset=malayalam

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add text in a non-english language?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/how-can-i-add-text-in-a-non-english-language)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53233