# How to write a text superscript

Tags: text-object

How can I write part of a text as superscript in blender? It looks like I cannot. So what will I do? Write it in Word and then transfer it as image to blender? I hope it is not complicated.

Comment: Could you add a picture of what you are expecting ? If it is for mathematical formula, you can produce SVG curves using LaTeX formatting for example (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72467/use-latex-in-blender).

Comment: No need a picture. I just want to know how to write a superscript in the text.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43528/create-subscript-text/43533#43533

Comment: @upstream there is no such option therefore Stef is asking for specifity to advise a workaround.